# Get all webs with certain property value

Tags: caml-query, site-collection, spweb, properties, query

If I have a certain number of webs within my site collection, and those web have set some property, eg. `web.Properties["foo"] = "bar"`. I'd like to get list of all the webs which have property `foo` set to `bar`. How can I do that?

One way is to iterate through all webs, but that doesn't seem efficient. What other possibilities do I have?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the property setting code of the web, you could have a quasi "index" in the RootWeb, which contains a csv or a list of webs with property values.

Then, to find webs with specific properties, all you need to do is query a property from the RootWeb (which is a property from the SPSite so you don't need to do a search).

Comment: looks interesting. How about SPPropetyBag limits? I estimate that there will be few thousand of webs.

Comment: That's a lot of webs. Maybe storing the "index" in the property bag is not the best solution.  You could store this index in a sharepoint list perhaps?